# How to disable rotation

Tags: release-loki

I'm using a touch laptop, I want to disable auto rotate, can not find an option that dies that, can you guide me please or provide a terminal line for it? Thanks for the Awesome OS.

Comment: I have the same issue with Loki on a Yoga 2 Pro. I submitted a bug request to see if they can adjust the sensitivity or allow one to turn off the feature.

Answer (score 3):

I resolved this issue (Yoga 2) by disabling rotation via three gsetting commands:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.touchscreen orientation-lock true

gsettings set com.ubuntu.touch.system orientation-lock 'PrimaryOrientation'

gsettings set com.ubuntu.touch.system rotation-lock true
```

You can check if those settings have changed with command:

```
gsettings list-recursively | grep '\-lock' | grep true
```

Then finally:

```
reboot
```

When the system boots back into elementary you should be rotate free.

Comment: I have tried to copy and paste onto the terminal but display flipped again.This is a beatiful and workable system,but display orientation is not a good idea on a non android device.I will be back when this bug is fixed and display orientation is removed,but thanks alot

Answer (score 1):

You can disable the rotation sensor with the following commands:

> sudo systemctl stop iio-sensor-proxy.service
>
> sudo systemctl disable iio-sensor-proxy.service

or

> sudo apt-get remove iio-sensor-proxy